# Using ASP.NET Core configuration settings for RavenDB connections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ravendb

How do I use appsettings.json in ASP.NET core to provide connection settings to RavenDB for different environments? The RavenDB docs explain how to do this with app.config and web.config, but I can't find anything for appsettings.json.

Is injecting an `IOptions<RavenSettings>` into the DocumentStoreHolder the right way to go (and what would this look like), or is there a better option?

Here's the code so far:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Raven": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "DefaultDatabase": "MyDatabase"
  } 
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    services.Configure<RavenSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Raven"));
}
```

**DocumentStoreHolder.cs**

```
public class DocumentStoreHolder
    {
        private static Lazy<IDocumentStore> docStore = new Lazy<IDocumentStore>(CreateStore);

        public static IDocumentStore Store
        {
            get { return docStore.Value; }
        }

        private static IDocumentStore CreateStore()
        {
            IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
            {
                Url = "http://localhost:8080",
                DefaultDatabase = "MyDatabase"
            }.Initialize();

            return store;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to read the individual values and set the properties directly on the `DocumentStore`. In 3.x RavenDB doesn't support reading the configuration from the `AppSettings.json` file

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be by using connection strings instead of separated configurations, so you can resolve connection string depending on current environment name as expected in asp net core platform, and pass the connection string all way down to get DocumentStore initialized for the first time.

```
private static IDocumentStore InitRavenDb(string connectionString)
{
    var optsBuilder = ConnectionStringParser<RavenConnectionStringOptions>.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
    optsBuilder.Parse();
    var opts = optsBuilder.ConnectionStringOptions;

    return new DocumentStore
    {
        Url = opts.Url,
        ApiKey = opts.ApiKey,
        DefaultDatabase = opts.DefaultDatabase,
    }.Initialize(true);
}


var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");


services.AddSingleton(_ => InitRavenDb(connectionString));
```